# how can I add this child field to parentDTO?

Tags: java, jhipster, dto, jdl

I have this two entities

```
entity Country {
name String                                                                                   
}                                                                             
entity Regions {
name String
population Integer                                                                            
}
```

And i wanna get something like this

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "USA",
"regions": 
        [
            {
                "id": 1                    
                "name": "florida"
                "population":150000"
            },
             {
                "id": 2                    
                "name": "newyork"
                "population":12"
            },
        ]
```

}

I also tried to do List regions in jdl but it doesnt work in jdl studio i get error!
Can you please tell me how to do it even with the code and Thanks.

Comment: Manual Code change please guided

Comment: As explained in your other question, your JDL should define a OneToMany relationship between Country and Region., see examples in the JDL doc. Then you can manually modify the generated Mapper to include missing fields, see MapStruct doc https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#defining-mapper

Comment: I already have a relationship between them but i didnt Know how to modify it manually and thanks for helping me